# UWP UserControl with its own ViewModel as well as Dependency Properties using Template 10

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, user-controls, uwp, template10

I am creating UWP app using Template 10 and MVVM. My requirement is to create UserControl which will have its own dependency properties as well as has it own ViewModel.

My Requirement:

1. Call Parent ViewModel command on Button Click.
2. Bind TexBlock text from UserControl ViewModel

My User Control looks like this:

```
  <vm:MyUserControl1  AddItem="{Binding MyCommand}"   Component="{Binding}"  RelativePanel.Below="abc" />
```

User Control XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Component.Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Click Me" Command="{x:Bind AddItem}">
            </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This is UserControl code behind code :

```
 public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //   mygrid.DataContext = this;
            (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddItemProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(
              "AddItem",
              typeof(ICommand),
              typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ICommand AddItem
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(AddItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ComponentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Component",typeof(MyViewModel),typeof(MyUserControl1),new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MyViewModel Component
        {
            get { return (MyViewModel)GetValue(ComponentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ComponentProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```

UserControl View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {

        }
        public string Text => "ABC";
    }
```

Parent View Model:

```
  public class SettingsPartViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
        DelegateCommand _MyCommand;

        public DelegateCommand MyCommand
            => _MyCommand ?? (_MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() => {
                  ///Some Code  
                });
            }));
     }
```

Whenever I run code I get following Error:

```
 Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsApp2.ViewModels.SettingsPartViewModel' to type 'WindowsApp2.ViewModels.MyViewModel'.
```

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going wrong here `Component="{Binding}"`. You're directly setting component to the parent view's DataContext i.e `WindowsApp2.ViewModels.SettingsPartViewModel` instead of `WindowsApp2.ViewModels.MyViewModel`.

For it to work properly, you need to create an instance of `MyViewModel` in your `SettingsPartViewModel` and bind it to the `Component`.

**Try below sample :**

In SettingsPartViewModel :

```
private MyViewModel myViewModelInstance = new MyViewModel();

public MyViewModel MyViewModelInstance
{
    get { return myViewModelInstance; }
    set { myViewModelInstance = value; //Raise NotifyPropertyChanged }
}
```

In SettingsPart.xaml :

```
<vm:MyUserControl1  AddItem="{Binding MyCommand}"   Component="{Binding MyViewModelInstance}"  RelativePanel.Below="abc" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Its working as expected now. But only issue now I am facing is If I change MyViewModel property value not reflecting on UI. I have tried doing Component="{Binding MyViewModelInstance,Mode=OneWay}" but still no luck. Can you plz help

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't help you. Try `Mode=TwoWay` and also check whether you have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface properly.

Comment: Done. Setting Component property mode to OneWay solved issue  Text="{x:Bind Component.Text,Mode=OneWay}". Everything is working like a charm. Thanks buddy!